# Output stays the same value

Tags: vhdl, fpga, state-machine, vivado

My PRN-Generator is not working. I want to do it with a linear feedback shift register.

The simulation and compiling are working without problems, but the output is wrong (lfsr_out = '0') and is not changing.

Code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity lfsr_counter is
  generic(
    WIDTH : integer := 10
  );
  port(
    clk      : in  std_logic;       --clock
    rst      : in  std_logic;       --positiv rst
    lfsr_out : out std_logic        --1 bit output of lfsr
  );
end lfsr_counter;

-------------------------------------------------------------------

architecture behavioral of lfsr_counter is
  type state_type is (state_rst, state_go); --rst: reset; go: lfsr 
shifts

  signal present_state : state_type;
  signal next_state    : state_type;
  signal lfsr          : std_logic_vector((WIDTH - 1) downto 0) := 
(others => '0');
  signal d0            : std_logic                              := '0'; 
--stores the current feedbackvalue

begin

  --sequencial logic:
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  state_register : process(clk, rst)
  begin
    if (rst = '1') then
      present_state <= state_rst; --default state on reset.
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
      present_state <= next_state; --state change
    end if;
  end process;

  --  combinatorial logic
  -------------------------------------------------------------------

  comb_logic : process(present_state, rst)
  begin
    case present_state is
      when state_rst =>
        if (rst = '1') then
          next_state <= state_rst;
        else
          next_state <= state_go;
        end if;
      when state_go =>
        if (rst = '1') then
          next_state <= state_rst;
        else
          next_state <= state_go;
        end if;
    end case;
  end process;

  output_logic : process(present_state)
  begin
    if (present_state = state_go) then
      --assert ((WIDTH >= 3) and (WIDTH <= 10))
      --report "Error: the LFSR width must be between 3 and 10" severity 
failure;
      case WIDTH is               --definitions for the feedback
        when 3      => d0 <= lfsr(2) xnor lfsr(1);
        when 4      => d0 <= lfsr(3) xnor lfsr(2);
        when 5      => d0 <= lfsr(4) xnor lfsr(2);
        when 6      => d0 <= lfsr(5) xnor lfsr(4);
        when 7      => d0 <= lfsr(6) xnor lfsr(5);
        when 8      => d0 <= lfsr(7) xnor lfsr(5) xnor lfsr(4) xnor 
lfsr(3);
        when 9      => d0 <= lfsr(8) xnor lfsr(4);
        when 10     => d0 <= lfsr(9) xnor lfsr(6);
        when others => null;
      end case;
      lfsr     <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(lfsr) sll 1); --shifting all 
bits to left by 1
      lfsr_out <= lfsr(WIDTH - 1); --MSB to output
      lfsr     <= lfsr(WIDTH - 1 downto 1) & d0; --concatenate the 
feedback to the lfsr
    else
      lfsr     <= (others => '0'); --reset state -> lfsr contains only 
'0'
      lfsr_out <= '0';
    end if;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

If you set "lfsr_out <= '1'" in output_logic, the output will stay '1'. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: don't use both `std_logic_unsigned` and `numeric_std`. Either use the latter and properly use `signed` and `unsigned` (preferred). Or write everything using the unsigned std_logic_vector (less readable imho).

Answer (score 3):

> What's wrong with my code?

Your shift register with a value of all '0's and XNOR will produce an output d0 of '1'. This is where the '1' comes from.

You could use a generate statement to produced d0 instead of a process statement with a case statement.

The first assignment to lfsr will have no effect and can be removed. There's only one projected output waveform for any scheduled time. An assignment without an after delay will incur a delta cycle. Two of those in the same delta cycle and the last one will take effect. As a consequence you don't need packages std_logic_unsigned (Synopsys) or numeric_std (IEEE).

**Synthesized results**

lfsr is not a clocked register, it's a combinatorial loop always producing '1' in synthesized hardware. That's caused by a lack of sequential shifting.

Also, how would your simulation be working without problems? Process output_logic will only resume for an event on present_state.

Throwing away the separate state machine and implementing a clocked lfsr shift register and using generate statements:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
-- use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
-- use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity lfsr_counter is
    generic (
        -- WIDTH: integer := 10
        WIDTH:  positive range 3 to 10 := 10
    );
    port (
        clk:       in  std_logic;
        rst:       in  std_logic;       -- positive rst
        lfsr_out:  out std_logic
    );
end entity lfsr_counter;

architecture behavioral of lfsr_counter is
    -- type state_type is (state_rst, state_go); 
    -- signal present_state:  state_type;
    -- signal next_state:     state_type;
    signal lfsr:    std_logic_vector((WIDTH - 1) downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal d0:             std_logic := '0'; 
begin
-- state_register:
--     process (clk, rst)
--         begin
--         if rst = '1' then
--             present_state <= state_rst;
--         elsif rising_edge(clk) then
--             present_state <= next_state;
--         end if;
--     end process;

-- comb_logic:  
    -- process (present_state, rst)
    -- begin
    --     case present_state is
    --         when state_rst =>
    --             if rst = '1' then
    --                 next_state <= state_rst;
    --             else
    --                 next_state <= state_go;
    --             end if;
    --         when state_go =>
    --             if rst = '1' then
    --                 next_state <= state_rst;
    --             else
    --                 next_state <= state_go;
    --             end if;
    --     end case;
    -- end process;

-- Using VHDL -2008 you could use a case generate or elsif
WIDTH3:
    if WIDTH = 3 generate
        d0 <= lfsr(2) xnor lfsr(1);
    end generate;
WIDTH4:
    if WIDTH = 4 generate
        d0 <= lfsr(3) xnor lfsr(2);
    end generate;
WIDTH5:
    if WIDTH = 5 generate
        d0 <= lfsr(4) xnor lfsr(2);
    end generate;
WIDTH6:
    if WIDTH = 6 generate
        d0 <= lfsr(5) xnor lfsr(4);
    end generate;
WIDTH7:
    if WIDTH = 7 generate
        d0 <= lfsr(6) xnor lfsr(5);
    end generate;
WIDTH8:
    if WIDTH = 8 generate
        d0 <= lfsr(7) xnor lfsr(5) xnor lfsr(4) xnor lfsr(3);
    end generate;
WIDTH9:
    if WIDTH = 9 generate
        d0 <= lfsr(8) xnor lfsr(4);
    end generate;
WIDTH10:
    if WIDTH = 10 generate
        d0 <= lfsr(9) xnor lfsr(6);
    end generate;
-- output_logic:
--     process (present_state)
--     begin
--     if present_state = state_go then
--         case WIDTH is
--             when 3   =>
--                 d0 <= lfsr(2) xnor lfsr(1);
--             when 4   =>
--                 d0 <= lfsr(3) xnor lfsr(2);
--             when 5   =>
--                 d0 <= lfsr(4) xnor lfsr(2);
--             when 6   =>
--                 d0 <= lfsr(5) xnor lfsr(4);
--             when 7   =>
--                 d0 <= lfsr(6) xnor lfsr(5);
--             when 8   =>
--                 d0 <= lfsr(7) xnor lfsr(5) xnor lfsr(4) xnor lfsr(3);
--             when 9   =>
--                 d0 <= lfsr(8) xnor lfsr(4);
--             when 10  =>
--                 d0 <= lfsr(9) xnor lfsr(6);
--             when others =>
--                 null;
--         end case;
--         -- lfsr     <= lfsr sll 1;
--         lfsr_out <= lfsr(WIDTH - 1);
--         lfsr     <= lfsr(WIDTH - 1 downto 1) & d0;
--     else
--         lfsr     <= (others => '0');
--         lfsr_out <= '0';
--         end if;
--     end process;
lfsr_reg:
    process (rst, clk)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            lfsr <= (others =>'0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            lfsr <= lfsr(WIDTH - 2 downto 0) & d0;  -- WAS WIDTH - 1 downto 1
        end if;
    end process;

    lfsr_out <= lfsr(WIDTH - 1);  -- not separately registered

end architecture;
```

The bit with the generate statement(s) does nothing interesting but offload work from synthesis, which would have to gate eat all those assignments in the case statement multiplexer.

Also with an added testbench to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we see lfsr doesn't actually shift left. The fix is shown in the code above and involves a change:

```
lfsr <= lfsr(WIDTH - 2 downto 0) & d0;  -- WAS WIDTH - 1 downto 1
```

The testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity lfsr_counter_tb is  -- a testbench
end entity;

architecture foo of lfsr_counter_tb is
    constant WIDTH:   positive range 1 to 10 := 10;  -- test full length
    signal clk:       std_logic := '1';
    signal rst:       std_logic := '0';
    signal lfsr_out:  std_logic;
begin
DUT:
    entity work.lfsr_counter
        generic map (
            WIDTH => WIDTH
        )
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            rst => rst,
            lfsr_out => lfsr_out
        );
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 550 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 11 ns;
        rst <= '1';
        wait for 99 ns;
        rst <= '0';
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

simulates:

[image: lfsr_counter_tb.png]

And lfsr_counter should synthesize and function as well.

> Uhhm. Never heard anything about the generate statement in our Digital Design course! this could be very useful in some cases. Thank you for this example. I understand your code. It is really simple and self-explaining. You can also avoid combinatorial loops. However, it is a different approach. I still would like to implement it as a FSM and understand the mechanisms of the FSM's. Now, I know that the output_logic part is not clocked and that this causes the comb. loop. Also that only the last statement of lfsr is being executed. What do I have to edit to make it work?

That as they say is a different question. A twofer special, today only.

Your code displays programming language thinking while VHDL is a hardware description language. For instance no signal update occurs while any process has yet to resume or subsequently suspend in the current simulation cycle.  This means d0 doesn't want to be a signal or it's assignments want to be in a separate process.

Signals communicate between processes. For an object that is solely used inside a process you should use a variable if the value is evaluated after assignment.

There's also the multiplexer using WIDTH to assign d0. It represents hardware that will get gate eaten during synthesis because WIDTH is unchanging, passed as a generic constant.

The generic constant can have a defined scalar range:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
-- use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
-- use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity lfsr_counter is
    generic (
        -- WIDTH: integer := 10
        WIDTH:  positive range 3 to 10 := 10
    );
    port (
        clk:       in  std_logic;
        rst:       in  std_logic;       -- positive rst
        lfsr_out:  out std_logic
    );
end entity lfsr_counter;
```

This allows writing VHDL design description that doesn't have to handle values outside what you use. All the extra logic gets gate eaten but you can introduce errors.

So with d0 made a variable, WIDTH constrained and the lsfr_out assignment moved to a concurrent statement:

```
architecture behave of lfsr_counter is
    type state_type is (state_rst, state_go);
    signal present_state:  state_type;
    signal next_state:     state_type;
    signal lfsr:    std_logic_vector((WIDTH - 1) downto 0) := (others => '0');
    -- signal d0:             std_logic := '0'; 
begin
state_register:
    process (clk, rst)
        begin
        if rst = '1' then
            present_state <= state_rst;
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            present_state <= next_state;
        end if;
    end process;

comb_logic:
    process (present_state, rst)
    begin
        case present_state is
            when state_rst =>
                if rst = '1' then
                    next_state <= state_rst;
                else
                    next_state <= state_go;
                end if;
            when state_go =>
                if rst = '1' then
                    next_state <= state_rst;
                else
                    next_state <= state_go;
                end if;
        end case;
    end process;

output_logic:
    process  (clk)  -- (present_state)
        variable d0: std_logic;
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if present_state = state_go then
                case WIDTH is
                    when 3   =>
                        d0 := lfsr(2) xnor lfsr(1);
                    when 4   =>
                        d0 := lfsr(3) xnor lfsr(2);
                    when 5   =>
                        d0 := lfsr(4) xnor lfsr(2);
                    when 6   =>
                        d0 := lfsr(5) xnor lfsr(4);
                    when 7   =>
                        d0 := lfsr(6) xnor lfsr(5);
                    when 8   =>
                        d0 := lfsr(7) xnor lfsr(5) xnor lfsr(4) xnor lfsr(3);
                    when 9   =>
                        d0 := lfsr(8) xnor lfsr(4);
                    when 10  =>
                        d0 := lfsr(9) xnor lfsr(6);
                    -- when others =>
                    --     null;
                end case;
                -- lfsr     <= lfsr sll 1;
                -- lfsr_out <= lfsr(WIDTH - 1);
                -- lfsr     <= lfsr(WIDTH - 1 downto 1) & d0;
                lfsr <= lfsr(WIDTH - 2 downto 0) & d0;
            else
                lfsr     <= (others => '0');  -- a synchronous reset
                -- lfsr_out <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    lfsr_out <= lfsr(WIDTH - 1);  -- not separately registered, a mux

end architecture behave;
```

All the changes from your first architecture are shown, original code commented out. This analyzes, elaborates and simulates with the same testbench and produces the same results.

The reason for moving the lfsr_out assignment is based on the same issue as d0, with another observation. The output_logic process will only resume execution when there is an event on a signal found the sensitivity list.

This would mean you would miss transitions on lfsr_out simulating your first design, or would imply a half clock delay (for the next clk edge) using a clocked lfsr register as in the above behave architecture.

You could note the lsfr assignment change to actually provide a shift as in the lfsr_reg process in the top code example. You'll note that first assignment to lfsr is still commented out.

Comment: Don't reset the lfsr to all zeroes, or it will enter an invalid state.

Comment: @gsm - your comment is incorrect, observe the waveform.

Comment: Indeed; I overlooked the use of XNORs instead of XORs, in which an all 1's state is invalid

Comment: Uhhm. Never heard anything about the generate statement in our Digital Design course! this could be very useful in some cases. Thank you for this example. I understand your code. It is really simple and self-explaining. You can also avoid combinatorial loops. However, it is a different approach. I still would like to implement it as a FSM and understand the mechanisms of the FSM's.
Now, I know that the output_logic part is not clocked and that this causes the comb. loop. Also that only the last statement of lfsr is being executed. What do I have to edit to make it work?